# Marmalade SDK 6.1: missing Studio UI Builder

Tags: marmalade

Marmalade SDK 6.1 they removed the UI Studio builder tool used in previous versions to construct the UI for apps.
http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/documentation#/tools/uibuilder.html

now is there any alternative to the tool or we have to construct the UI programmatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\Marmalade\6.0.6\tools\UIBuilder\Readme.txt
```

> The Marmalade Studio UI Builder has been removed from the Marmalade SDK.
>   This means it is no longer a supported part of the product.
>
> We have removed the UI Builder because we believe that, going forwards,
>   it is better for the Marmalade UI runtimes to support a standard UI markup
>   rather than our proprietary markup. In the 6.1 release, we plan to support
>   a standard UI markup, meaning that developers can leverage multiple 3rd party
>   tools (including free tools) that support that markup.
>
> Our plan for the 6.0.1 release is to make the UI Builder source code publicly
>   available, together with full instructions on how to build it. In the meantime,
>   developers can still use the UI Builder tool by installing the most recent 5.2.x
>   SDK version.
>
> There is no plan to abandon support for the current ITX markup for the IwUI
>   runtime. Developers can continue to create ITX markup, either through the UI
>   Builder tool or by hand, and be sure that the ITX markup will be usable in
>   future versions of the IwUI runtime.

Comment: This is strange, although they still use the UI files in the new SDK sample apps

Comment: I found the answer in 6.0.6 and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a XML UI builder available for Marmalade too. You can check it out [here](http://iberlynx.com/index.php/es/2011-07-07-10-32-54/mobile-version).